# Trying to compare multiple consecutive elements of a 2D array of Lables

Tags: multidimensional-array, reference, label, traversal

I have a 2d array of `Label`s, each label contains a `String` version of an `int`. I'm attempting to traverse my array and check to see if each element contains the same `int`. Am I going about this the wrong way?

```
public boolean isPattern(Label[][] matirx) {     

        boolean pattern = false;

        for (int rPos = 0; rPos < rows; rPos++) {
            for (int cPos = 0; cPos < columns - 3; cPos++) {
                if (matrix[cPos][rPos].equals(matrix[cPos + 1][rPos]) 
                        && matrix[cPos][rPos].equals(matrix[cPos + 2][rPos])
                        && matrix[cPos][rPos].equals(matrix[cPos + 3][rPos])) {
                    pattern = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

When I print my `boolean` to the output window, I get `false` no matter what. So I guess my real question is. Am I comparing the contents of each `Label` or the value at each index, thus causing the variable never to be `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up using this solution:

```
for (int rPos = 0; rPos < rows - 3; rPos++) {
            for (int cPos = 0; cPos < columns; cPos++) {
                if (matrix[cPos][rPos].getText().equals(matrix[cPos][rPos + 1].getText())
                        && matrix[cPos][rPos].getText().equals(matrix[cPos][rPos + 2].getText())
                        && matrix[cPos][rPos].getText().equals(matrix[cPos][rPos + 3].getText())) {
                    pattern = true;
```

Works as needed. If anyone comes across this and knows a better way, please do share.